# Clustering of accelerometer events

Tags: time-series, clustering

Refer to the images below. I have an accelerometer attached to a door that logs events everytime someone opens and closes a door.

I'm attempting to predict the individual who opened or closed the door based on how they exert force on the door during the event.

In the images I've given examples of 2 separate people opening the door and you can see minor variations in their behaviour.

I'm at this stage exploring a cluster/classification solution to identifying the individual related to each event.

Any help on finding an approximate solution would be great!
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I find that discrete wavelet transforms might help me conduct clustering, but I'm not an expert on the theory behind it. Any lay-man interpretations of how to carry it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a common task done in analyzing neurological events, known as

[Spike Sorting (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spike_sorting).

[Spike Sorting (Scholarpedia)](http://scholarpedia.org/article/Spike_sorting) - much more details.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it is just a simple ideia, I don't know if it would really work:

You could get a simple distance between those signals, for example:

$$ |S_{1}(t)-S_{2}(t)|^2 = \int_{0}^{T} (S_{1}(t)-S_{2}(t))^2 dt $$

As that defines a metric between all your samples, you can use the **K-means** clustering algorithm to get some clusters.

Comment: This looks like a promising approach when (a) the onset of each signal can be reliably identified and (b) all signals from each individual have common durations and amplitudes.  Although (a) looks likely--the acceleration starts suddenly after a long quiet period--(b) does not look plausible. For good results, some initial processing seems required in order to obtain reliable comparisons among separate signals so that (1) all signals by one individual are as alike as possible while (2) maximizing the differences between signals from two separate individuals.

Comment: Thanks eqperes for your input. Will explore this approach.

Comment: @whuber I'm doing something along the lines of what you've suggested. Feature extraction seems key to be able to take this ahead.